# Is it safe to exclude my own registered domain from rebinding protection?

Tags: dns-rebinding

I want to access my web server from the LAN and from the internet using the same name (`www.my-own-domain.example`). However, my router (*Fritz!box*) has rebind protection enabled and does not resolve DNS requests to local addresses. The router gives the option to exclude specific domains from this protection, but warns strongly to do so.

As I understand the rebinding security issue, it should be safe to exclude from the rebind protection a domain that I own.

Is my understanding correct or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

After additional Internet searches, I cannot provide an authoritative answer, but I found additional supportive evidence that it is safe to exclude own domains.

- on https://umbrella.cisco.com/blog/2008/04/14/finally-a-real-solution-to-dns-rebinding-attacks/ Cisco advices for their routers that addresses legitimately pointing to LAN addresses should be excluded:

> Those of you with domains that point to private address space
>   legitimately (to your intranet, for example) should also visit the
>   domain whitelist page and whitelist your domain.

- on https://superuser.com/questions/1220839/my-router-false-positively-detects-dns-rebind-attack an answer is provided that recommends excluding the own domain in a situation similar to mine (but not commenting on the safety of that approach)

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on the topic:

AFAIK, a domain and DNS Server under the attacker's control are required for DNS rebinding to work.

Because you own the domain, the attacker would have to make DNS requests to `my-own-domain.example` use a DNS server under the attacker's control. So he/she would have to compromise a DNS server or intercept the DNS traffic between your router and the preconfigured DNS servers. DNS over TLS/HTTPS and DNSSEC can help to mitigate this risk.

Comment: What about DNS configuration manipulation, sinkholes and etc?